# api-gateway with Spring cloud with zuul and consul for service discovery

Tags: consul, netflix-zuul, api-gateway, spring-cloud-consul

I am trying to create a small API-gateway which employs Spring-cloud with Zuul as proxy and consul as service discovery.

Following is my bootstrap.properties:-

```
spring.application.name=APIGateway
spring.cloud.consul.config.enabled=true
spring.cloud.consul.config.host=localhost
spring.cloud.consul.config.port=8500
server.port=8084
security.basic.enable=false   
management.security.enabled=false
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.fail-fast=true
ribbon.ConnectTimeout=30000
ribbon.ReadTimeout=30000
ribbon.eureka.enabled=false
ribbon.consul.enabled=true
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=60000
```

application.properties:-

```
zuul.routes.notificationservice.serviceId=notification-service
zuul.routes.tradeservice.serviceId=trade-data-service
zuul.routes.refdataservice.serviceId=ref-data-service
zuul.routes.notificationservice.path=/notificationservice/**
zuul.routes.tradeservice.path=/tradeservice/**
zuul.routes.refdataservice.path=/refdataservice/**
zuul.host.socket-timeout-millis=30000
```

My Java App:-

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableZuulProxy
public class MetallicaZuulServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MetallicaZuulServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

When I run my microservice and gateway, I can see that my consul has both of them registered with it. However, when I request one of my micro services (Ex:- http://localhost:8084/refdataservice) I get a ZuulException: Forwarding Error.

Am I missing something? What could be the reason for same?

Following is the stack trace:-

```
2017-12-28 18:36:52.198  INFO 12004 --- [nio-8084-exec-6] c.n.l.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer      : DynamicServerListLoadBalancer for client ref-data-service initialized: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=ref-data-service,current list of Servers=[10.207.101.27:0],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {unknown=[Zone:unknown;   Instance count:1;   Active connections count: 0;    Circuit breaker tripped count: 0;   Active connections per server: 0.0;]
},Server stats: [[Server:10.207.101.27:0;   Zone:UNKNOWN;   Total Requests:0;   Successive connection failure:0;    Total blackout seconds:0;   Last connection made:Thu Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 1970;  First connection made: Thu Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 1970;    Active Connections:0;   total failure count in last (1000) msecs:0; average resp time:0.0;  90 percentile resp time:0.0;    95 percentile resp time:0.0;    min resp time:0.0;  max resp time:0.0;  stddev resp time:0.0]
]}ServerList:ConsulServerList{serviceId='ref-data-service', tag=null}
2017-12-28 18:36:53.163  INFO 12004 --- [erListUpdater-0] c.netflix.config.ChainedDynamicProperty  : Flipping property: ref-data-service.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit to use NEXT property: niws.loadbalancer.availabilityFilteringRule.activeConnectionsLimit = 2147483647
2017-12-28 18:36:53.632  WARN 12004 --- [nio-8084-exec-6] o.s.c.n.z.filters.post.SendErrorFilter   : Error during filtering

com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.handleException(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:189) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:164) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:111) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:112) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:193) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:157) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:118) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:157) [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequest(ZuulController.java:44) [spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50) [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: null
    at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:118) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.support.AbstractRibbonCommand.run(AbstractRibbonCommand.java:117) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.support.AbstractRibbonCommand.run(AbstractRibbonCommand.java:46) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:302) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar:1.5.12]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:298) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar:1.5.12]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10247) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10214) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.BlockingOperatorToFuture.toFuture(BlockingOperatorToFuture.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.toFuture(BlockingObservable.java:411) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.queue(HystrixCommand.java:378) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar:1.5.12]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.execute(HystrixCommand.java:344) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar:1.5.12]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:158) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    ... 67 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 10.207.101.27:80 [/10.207.101.27] failed: Connection refused: connect
    at rx.exceptions.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:58) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:464) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single(BlockingObservable.java:341) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:112) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    ... 129 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 10.207.101.27:80 [/10.207.101.27] failed: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:159) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.apache.RetryableRibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient$1.doWithRetry(RetryableRibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.java:130) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.apache.RetryableRibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient$1.doWithRetry(RetryableRibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.java:102) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287) ~[spring-retry-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:164) ~[spring-retry-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.apache.RetryableRibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.executeWithRetry(RetryableRibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.java:160) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.apache.RetryableRibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.execute(RetryableRibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.java:144) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.apache.RetryableRibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.execute(RetryableRibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.java:54) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient$1.call(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:104) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$3$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:303) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$3$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:287) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$3.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:231) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$3.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:228) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap$ConcatMapSubscriber.drain(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:286) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap$ConcatMapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:144) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:185) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:180) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:94) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:42) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10247) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10214) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:444) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    ... 131 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    ... 167 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Could it be, that your network is not configured correctly or not set up correctly in the zuul config?
Caused by: HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 10.207.101.27:80 [/10.207.101.27] failed: Connection refused: connect

Comment: My first guess is that only. But I don't know how to verify that. I could see that the services are properly registered with consul. My gateway is also registered with consul. I am not sure how to check if my network is configured correctly with zuul.